# Using Blaze Persistence optional parameter in subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, blaze-persistence

In Blaze Persistence, is there a way to use an optional parameter in a subquery?

In my current use case, let's say I have topics, users, and a third table called `topic_last_seen` to record the date at which each user has last read each topic. I would like to create an entity view for the `Topic` entity which also maps that date for each topic with the current user given as an "optional parameter". This is roughly what I've been trying:

```
@EntityView(Topic.class)
public interface TopicView
{
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();

    String getSummary();

    @MappingParameter("currentUserId")
    Long getCurrentUserId();

    @MappingSubquery(LastSeenDateSubqueryProvider.class)
    Date getLastSeenDate();

    class LastSeenDateSubqueryProvider implements SubqueryProvider
    {
        @Override
        public <T> T createSubquery(SubqueryInitiator<T> subqueryBuilder)
        {
            return subqueryBuilder.from(TopicLastSeen.class, "lastSeen")
                    .select("dateSeen")
                    .where("lastSeen.user.id").eqExpression("EMBEDDING_VIEW(currentUserId)")
                    .where("lastSeen.topic.id").eqExpression("EMBEDDING_VIEW(id)")
                    .end();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'currentUserId' not found on type 'Topic'
```

Is there any way to use an optional parameter in a subquery like this at all? Or is there a different way to map this information? Changing the DB schema is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured this out a possible suolution by trial and error. It seems that the "optional parameters" from `EntityViewSetting` can be used like regular parameters in JPQL:

```
return subqueryBuilder.from(TopicLastSeen.class, "lastSeen")
        .select("dateSeen")
        .where("lastSeen.user.id").eqExpression(":currentUserId")
        .where("lastSeen.topic.id").eqExpression("EMBEDDING_VIEW(id)")
        .end();
```

Unfortunately though, with this subquery mapping the currentUserId parameter is no longer "optional". When it is not set I get another exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : currentUserId
```

Comment: It's true that the parameter is no longer optional, but the nice thing about `EntityViewSetting.addOptionalParameter` is that it doesn't fail if the parameter does not exist in the query, so if you don't have a value, you can set it to null or something like that :)

Comment: @ChristianBeikov That is exactly what I'm doing now. I only just discovered Blaze Persistence and wasn't sure if this was the way to go. Thanks for your feedback and also for your work on Blaze Persistence!